# How to access $variables in a module function where $variables is not passed to it. (D7)

Tags: 7

I have a custom module that retrieves a view.

I would like to set a page variable that sums up a bunch of fields as im iterating through them.

So how to i access the `$variables` variable if it isnt an argument of my function?

Answer (score 1):

Call your function from inside your module's preprocess_page() hook.  Eg, in your custom module, let's say your function that calls your view is mymodule_call_view().  Let's further assume it returns the value you want to set your page variable to.  You could do it this way:

```
mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // any other preprocessing you are doing goes here

  $variables['variable_you_want_to_set']=mymodule_call_view();

}
```

Then, when drupal is building the page, it would call your preprocess function, which would call your function that iterates through the view, etc...